# How to use winform control VirtualTree of infralution in VCL.net?

Tags: .net, delphi

I'm trying to use the VirtualTree of Infralution in VCL.NET, does anyone knows how to do this? In Delphi 8 was a wrapper tool, but i'm using Delphi 2007.

VirtualTree
http://www.infralution.com/forums.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The wrapper tool is called *WinForms Control Package* (to import WinForms controls) is not available in RAD Studio 2007, only is present in Delphi 8 to Delphi 2006 (.Net 1.1).

if you have one of these old versions (D8, D2005, D2006), you can use the tool to create the units (wrappers) and then use them in Delphi 2007. but the most likely have to modify much of the code generated.

Another option is use [Hydra](http://www.remobjects.com/hydra.aspx).

As a final recommendation, considers switch to [Delphi Prism](http://www.embarcadero.com/products/delphi-prism), since Delphi 2007.Net is no longer supported.

Bye.

Comment: I have somewhere Delphi 2006, so i wil take a look at that. 

Hydra is for using Dot net in Delphi Win32, so that is no use in this situation

I want the VCL in dot net because otherwise i can move to WPF at once, but that is a lot of work....